# Enter "&" symbol into a text Label in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, special-characters

How would one enter special characters into a `Label` in C# (Windows Forms)?

If you try to write a "&" into a label you'll get a sort of underscore instead..

So what's the C# equivalent of "&"? ("\&" obviously doesn't work).

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Two ways:

- Escape it with another ampersand (`&&`).
- Set [`UseMnemonic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) for that label to `false`. This causes all ampersands within the text to be taken literally so you don't need to double any of them. You'll lose the underlining and access key features though.

  You can set the value either in the designer, or in code:

  ```
  myLabel.UseMnemonic = false;
  myLabel.Text = "Text&Text";
  ```

Comment: I already knew (and used) the `&&` pattern but the `UseMnemonic` i never saw before. So +1 for this new enlightening.

Comment: This is the canonical answer. Duplicates to this question includes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324310, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737532, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100607 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324310.

Comment: Since `ToolStripStatusLabel` doesn't have this property, if I want to use this on a StatusStrip am I forced to escape it with another ampersand?

Comment: @McAdam331: I believe so.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks. It was easy enough to do, I just used `String.Replace("&", "&&")` whenever I set the text, so I could escape the ampersand without mutating my object itself and screw up how it's displayed elsewhere.

Comment: In Delphi, the `UseMnemonic` equivalent is `ShowAccelChar`.

Answer (score 20):

Add another ampersand in front of it, so: `&&`

Or have a look at the following: [Label.UseMnemonic (MSDN documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You can escape & by adding it two times, to try `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use '&' in the designer, but in the code you can use '&&' for showing one '&'

Comment: "&&" works fine in the designer. Just input it where you change the Text.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
((char)0x26).ToString()
```