# Showing an underscore (_) inside a label in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable WPF label accelerator key (text underscore is missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733/disable-wpf-label-accelerator-key-text-underscore-is-missing)

I am currently working on a C# WPF project. I need to read in a configuration file and display the options retrieved inside a label. The options are sometimes labelled with an underscore (_) in the middle of the option name, for example, it might be something like `my_option`.

When I try to display `my_option` inside a label, the underscore is hidden and is instead used as a keyboard shortcut when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed.

How can I disable this from happening and instead show the underscore in the label?

I have tried doing it so it is `my__option` (that is, adding two underscores together instead of one), but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Guess: Try escaping the underscore with a backslash

Comment: @SimpleCoder, I did try that but it Visual Studio displayed the error that it was an unrecognised escape sequence

Comment: Why a label and not a textblock?

Comment: This, maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/c-enter-symbol-into-a-text-label

Comment: @Boardy, then you have to escape the backslash: `\\_`.

Comment: @Dr McKay, that is WinForms this is about WPF.

Comment: The "exact duplicate" question doesn't answer this question. That question says that `__` works. It also says you can't do what you want with a label. So to answer this question: i dunno - it should work.

Comment: @Boardy, could you please post some code that shows this behavior with the double underscores?  In my testing I always can get the double underscores to work.  If you can post an example where it does not work then we can go from there.

Comment: I've got it working based on what @erno said and used a textblock instead of a label. Thanks for your help