# Stop ampersand from being turned into a mnemonic/accelerators for Windows Forms binding

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enter “&” symbol into a text Label in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/enter-symbol-into-a-text-label-in-windows-forms)

On a screen with label controls bound to user-filled properties, I'm getting underlined characters (mnemonics) on the label because the underlying data contains ampersands.

For example, if the bound property contains "A&B Trucking", then the label shows as "AB Trucking" with the B underlined. Alt-B on the keyboard would focus that label.

How do you prevent this from happening with bound controls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prevent this by either doubling up on the ampersands (&& will display correctly as &), or you can set the UseMnemonic property of the label to false which is probably the best solution in your case

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the situation you can either set [`UseMnemonic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) to `false` on the respective control (works for example with databinding) OR double the ampersand (and thus escaping it). For a walkthrough see [this](http://moiashvin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/05/escape-ampersand-character-in-c.html).

Answer (score 3):

Set the label's `UseMnemonic` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `A&&B Trucking` instead.