# inserting a & into a label

Tags: c#, winforms

EDIT#2

> I changed the Title name because it no longer represented the
>   question I am asking.  It turns out my problem was displaying the &
>   symbol in a c# winforms label.
>
> [Enter "&" symbol into a text Label in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/enter-symbol-into-a-text-label-in-windows-forms)
>
> That is the answer to the question which turns out is a duplicate

This was the original

I am currently using c# and sql.  I have no problem writing to the database, when I check the field using MS SQL Server Manager, I can see the & symbol in the varchar field.  but when I retrieve it using c# it seems to be omitted.

```
myTable.myColumn =" Me & You";

string testString="";
SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection(...)
SQLCommand command=new SQLCommand("Select Top 1 * from myTable",con)
SQLDataReader reader= command.ExecuteQuery()
while (reader.read())
{
    testString=reader["myColumn"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(testString);
}
```

output = Me You

I wrote this on the fly, it likely is not syntactically correct.  Is this normal output or do I likely have a mistake somewhere?

EDIT #1  so it turns out that the MessageBox does display the &.  The object this loads into holds the & symbol as well.  Even the label that is displaying the symbol holds the & symbol in its .Text property  eg. myLabel.Text == "Me & You".  but the display to the screen still says Me you.  so the Problem has nothing to do with SQL, but simply to do with Winforms, I will Likely delete this question shortly, unless someone else has experienced this and can offer some insight to speed my troubleshooting

Comment: There should be nothing special about retrieving an & from the database. Bear in mind it is a special character for HTML (if this is relevant). If the above was written quickly and is not correct does that mean you haven't actually tested to see if it exhibits the behaviour you are describing? Because if you haven't then helping you becomes really hard...

Comment: This is not the actual code I used, but this is what I believe is happened, or I should say believed.  See Edit#1 above

Comment: you will be use \ before symbol using replace string command before assign variable

Comment: @vikramjain sorry I don't understand that comment...

Comment: @K'Leg: This is exactly why I made that comment. I had a suspicion that the above code would work. Often while trying to make (and test) a minimal test case (ie the smallest code that reproduces the problem) you find out a heck of a lot more about what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTable.myColumn =" Me & You";

string testString="";
SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection(...)
SQLCommand command=new SQLCommand("Select Top 1 * from myTable",con)
SQLDataReader reader= command.ExecuteQuery()
while (reader.read())
{
    testString=reader["myColumn"].ToString().Replace("&","&&");
    MessageBox.Show(testString);
}
```

Comment: perfect that is the answer.  I am going with useMnemonic=false property of the label, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/enter-symbol-into-a-text-label-in-windows-forms  because I will be reinserting the string back into the database, and those && will add up over time.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the **`&`** is being used as a special character when you use a WinForms **`Label`**.

Where:

> Me & You

becomes

[image]

And

> Me && You

becomes

[image]

But that doesn't apply to a `MessageBox.Show`

---

[If it's a label:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325107/12597)

- Escape it with another ampersand (&&)
- Set [`UseMnemonic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) for that label to **false**, then all ampersands for that label will be taken literally and you don't need to double them (you lose the underlining/access key features though)

Comment: The message box does have a label to display the message.

Comment: see edit #1, though I think you are on to something because it is a label I am using.  Damn psuedo code, I should have used the original stuff but it is 200 lines long

Comment: The & in WinForms is used to mark the following character as the ALT-shortcut. Default settings in Windows makes you only see that underlined character if you press the ALT-key. Clever... :-)

Comment: So how can I take a string loaded from a database that includes the & symbol and put it in a label

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/enter-symbol-into-a-text-label-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

To use characters that have special meaning to the operating system, such as "and" ampersand (&) or semicolon (;), enclose the character in quotation marks ("). Separator columns can be n 'any 8-bit character.

Comment: but I am loading it from a sql database, not hardcoding it?

Comment: set your caracter between '&'