# '&' is being shown as '_' in a string c#

Tags: c#

I want to set the error message to text box using error provider.

```
 string strNotAllowedError = "The following characters are not allowed:  \' # & < > or \"";
 errorProvider1.SetError(this.txtbx1, strNotAllowedError);
```

but the on the screen error message is become like :
   The following characters are not allowed:'# _ < > or"
Here & is replaced by _ 
Please let me know how to show & in error message as it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter "&" symbol into a text Label in Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/enter-symbol-into-a-text-label-in-windows-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double up the `&` character.

Traditionally, `&` in strings (that are going to be displayed in the windows UI) is used to precede the keyboard accelerator character. Which when rendered is underlined. If you'd not had a space after the `&`, you'd have seen whatever character followed underlined, rather than seeing it as the `&` being *replaced* by a `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Use &&

this should do it

```
 string strNotAllowedError = "The following characters are not allowed:  \' # && < > or \"";
 errorProvider1.SetError(this.textBox1, strNotAllowedError);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this by `doubling the ampersand &&`:

```
string strNotAllowedError = "The following characters are not allowed:  \' # && < > or \"";
```

instead of this:

```
string strNotAllowedError = "The following characters are not allowed:\' # & < > or \"";
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try using &&& instead of & in the error message. Here is thread discussing about this
http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1649/Csharp.aspx?df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=3225091&tid=3225091