# Display a String with Ampersand in GroupBox and TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code like so (simplifying for the question):

```
public const string THIS_AND_THAT = "This & That";

System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox myGroupBox;
System.Windows.Forms.TreeView myTreeView;
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode myTreeNode;

myGroupBox.Text = THIS_AND_THAT;

myTreeNode = new TreeNode(THIS_AND_THAT);
myTreeNode.Name = THIS_AND_THAT;
myTreeView.Nodes.Add(THIS_AND_THAT);
```

With this code, the `GroupBox` displays as "This  That" and the `TreeView` displays correctly as "This & That".

So I changed the string ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325094/enter-symbol-into-a-text-label-in-windows-forms)) to this:

```
public const string THIS_AND_THAT = "This && That";
```

In this case, the `GroupBox` displays correctly as "This & That", but the `TreeView` displays as "This && That".
I don't see that I can use [UseMnemonic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) Property on the GroupBox or TreeView.

What do I do?

Comment: You can't use the same strings verbatim for TreeView and GroupBox, you will need to provide an escaped version for some controls and an unescaped version for other controls.

Comment: The is correct so you can make this into an answer.

Comment: Avoid `public const String Foo` only expose `const` values as `internal` because of how the compiler works. For publically exposed values you should use `public static String Foo { get; } = "Value";` instead, or if you really need a field use `public static readonly String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Promoting my comment to an answer):

There is inconsistency in how different controls in Windows and WinForms handle strings displayed to the user, as you've discovered `TreeView` does not support escaped ampersands while `GroupBox` does.

Fortunately it's straightforward to provide appropriate text:

```
String text = "This && that";

myGroupBox.Text = text;
myTreeNode.Text = text.Replace("&&", "&");
```